# Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by equation $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2, 2xy)$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, complex-numbers, vector-analysis

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ be defined by equation
>   $$f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2, 2xy)$$
>   Take $S$ to be the set
>   $$S=\{(x,y): x^2+y^2\leq a^2 \text{ and } x\geq 0 \text{ and } y\geq 0\}$$
>
> (a) Calculate $Df$ and $\det Df$.
>
> (b) Sketch the image under $f$ of the set $S$.
>
> [Hint: Parametrize part of the boundary of $S$ by setting $x = a \cos t$ and
>   $y = a \sin t$; find the image of this curve. Proceed similarly for the rest of
>   the boundary of $S$.]
>
> We remark that if one identifies the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ in the usual way, then $f$ is just the function $f(z) = z^2$.

For (a), $Df(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}2x & -2y\\2y  & 2x\end{bmatrix}$ and $\det \begin{bmatrix}2x & -2y\\2y  & 2x\end{bmatrix}=4x^2+4y^2=4(x^2+y^2)$

I would like to know what $\det Df$ is for, could someone please tell me?

I do not understand what I have to do in (b), could someone help me please? Thank you

Comment: You'll see what $det  Df$ is for when you learn the change of variables theorem for multiple integrals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $z=r(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta)$, then $z^2=r^2\bigl(\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta)\bigr)$. So, since $S$ is the intersection of

- the closed disk centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $a$;
- the first quadrant

its image under $f$ is the top half of the closed disk centered at $(0,0)$ with   radius $a^2$.

Comment: $S$ is not a disk, but a quarter of a disk.

Comment: @Jose27 I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos why "its image under $f$ is the top half of the closed disk centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $a^2$"?

Comment: @user482152 Because the elements of $S$ are those $z\in\mathbb C$ which can be written as $r\bigl(\cos\theta+i\sin\theta\bigr)$ with $0\leqslant r\leqslant a$ and $\theta\in\left[0,\frac\pi2\right]$. Since, for each such $z$, $f(z)=r^2\bigl(\cos(2\theta)+i\sin(2\theta)\bigr)$, the elements of $f(S)$ are those complex numbers $z$ which can be written as $r(\cos\mu+i\sin\mu)$ with $0\leqslant r\leqslant a^2$ and $\mu\in[0,\pi]$. That's the top half of the closed disk centered at $(0,0)$ with radius $a^2$.