# Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x, y) = (e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y)$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

**Let $f: \mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(x, y) = (e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y)$.**

**Take $S$ to be the set $S = [0, 1]\times [0, \pi]$.**

**(a) Calculate $Df$ and $\det Df$.**

**(b) Sketch the image under $f$ of the set $S$.**

**We remark that if one identifies $\mathbb{C}$ with $\mathbb{R}^2$ as usual, then $f$ is the function $f(z) = e^z$.**

For (a), $Df(x,y)=\begin{bmatrix}e^x \cos y & -e^x \sin y\\e^x \sin y  & e^x \cos y\end{bmatrix}$ and $\det \begin{bmatrix}e^x \cos y & -e^x \sin y\\e^x \sin y  & e^x \cos y\end{bmatrix}=e^{2x}\cos^2 y+e^{2x}\sin^2 y=e^{2x}$

I do not understand what I have to do in (b), could someone help me please? Thank you

Comment: since the sketch of $f$ is a surface then i think it's better to sketch it on a software

Comment: The set $S$ is $[0, 1] \times [0, \pi]$, so the image of $S$ under $f$ is the set $\{(e^x \cos y, e^x \sin y) | x \in [0, 1], y \in [0, \pi]\}$. At a guess, I'd say this was the top half of an annulus.

Comment: The image just a subset of the plane.  You shouldn't need software to sketch, and if you use a computer program, you won't learn anything.

Comment: Sort of duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2578048/let-f-mathbbr2-to-mathbbr2-be-defined-by-equation-fx-y-x2-y2-2x...

Comment: This question has been down-voted and cited as "sort of duplicate", but I'm up-voting it because the answers given as to how to sketch the image set are substantially different for each question.

Comment: I partially agree with saulspatz comment (above) and partially disagree.  I would invest 30 minutes to an hour attempting to sketch it by hand, and then use (some sort of) computer software to sketch it more precisely.  Then I would compare the manual and computer generated sketch, and see if I made an error.  If I couldn't come up with anything manual after an hour, I would study the computer generated sketch and **try to understand** why this sketch is accurate.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: The domain is a rectangular region. Start by sketching the images of its sides. E.g., one side of the rectangle is $\{(t,0)\mid t\in[0,1]\}$. Plug this into $f$, producing $(e^t,0)$, and draw the resulting curve.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Fix an $x$. Can you draw the image of $\{x\}\times [0,\pi]$ under $f$? What happens when you start varying $x$?

Answer (score 0):

For b)  Note that Firs value is $f(x,0)=(e^x,0).$

Since $x\in [0,1]$ this is the line segment between the points $(1,0)$ and $(e,0)$.

Second value is $f(x,\pi)=(-e^x,0).$

Since $x\in [0,1]$ this is the line segment between the points $(1,0)$ and $(-e,0)$.

Third value is $f(0,\theta)=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta).$

Since $\theta\in [0,\pi],$  that gives the upper unit semicircle.

Final value is $f(1,\theta)=(e \cos \theta, e \sin \theta).$

Since $\theta \in [0, \pi]$, that gives the upper unit semicircle which its center at the origin and with radius $e.$

The graph is

[image]